# Flash data not being written to session

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-7, inertiajs

Im using Laravel 7.12.0 and my flash session data doesn't appear to be working at all either using

`request()->session()->flash('status', 'Task was successful!');`

or

`return redirect()->route('home')->with('status', "Task was successful");`

I am using Debugbar as well as dd'ing the page to check session data.

I also know that the web middleware is being used.

`session()->put()` still works so I know putting data into the session aren't entirely broken but flash data does not seem to work at all. This is a fresh installation so I am struggling to see what could be wrong?

Web.php

```
Auth::routes();


Route::get('/', 'HomeController@index')->name('home');

Route::group(['middleware' => ['auth']], function () {
    Route::resource('polls', 'PollController');
    Route::post('polls/vote', 'PollController@vote')->name('polls.vote');
});

Route::resource('api/polls', 'API\PollController');
```

Part of `RouteServiceProvider.php`

```
    /**
     * Define the "web" routes for the application.
     *
     * These routes all receive session state, CSRF protection, etc.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    protected function mapWebRoutes()
    {
        Route::middleware('web')
            ->namespace($this->namespace)
            ->group(base_path('routes/web.php'));
    }
```

Web Middleware group in kernel.php

```
    /**
     * The application's route middleware groups.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $middlewareGroups = [
        'web' => [
            \App\Http\Middleware\EncryptCookies::class,
            \Illuminate\Cookie\Middleware\AddQueuedCookiesToResponse::class,
            \Illuminate\Session\Middleware\StartSession::class,
            // \Illuminate\Session\Middleware\AuthenticateSession::class,
            \Illuminate\View\Middleware\ShareErrorsFromSession::class,
            \App\Http\Middleware\VerifyCsrfToken::class,
            \Illuminate\Routing\Middleware\SubstituteBindings::class,
        ],

        'api' => [
            'throttle:60,1',
            \Illuminate\Routing\Middleware\SubstituteBindings::class,
        ],
    ];
```

HomeController.php

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;

class HomeController extends Controller
{

    public function index()
    {
        dd(request()->session()->all());
    }
}
```

What is in the session from my HomeController@index after being redirected.

```
  "_token" => "pbZJgfC6XNG2eTqlcGADm68NqhjOHI16rWe4U1bt"
  "_previous" => array:1 [▼
    "url" => "http://127.0.0.1:8000"
  ]
  "_flash" => array:2 [▼
    "old" => []
    "new" => []
  ]
  "url" => []
  "login_web_59ba36addc2b2f9401580f014c7f58ea4e30989d" => 1
]
```

Thanks

Comment: why you say it does not work?

Comment: In your `home` route, what do you do with the session? Do you display it anywhere, do you perform another redirect or what happens?

Comment: @Qirel In HomeController@index all I have is `dd(request()->session()->all());` just for the sake of seeing what session data it has. I'll edit my post to display what I get as a response.

Comment: does `withErrors()` works ?

Answer (score 1):

Seems as though this has to do with the hosting environment. I was able to reproduce the issue on my local machine when using http://127.0.0.1:8000. After switching to http://localhost:8000 the sessions started to persist as expected with both ->flash and ->with.

Comment: Thanks but still didn't resolve the issue. I am still getting the same result.

Comment: Can I see your controller by chance?

Comment: Thanks... in which controller are you calling the redirect above?

Comment: A controller named `PollController`. For now the controller method only contains the redirect and nothing else. It is called from `PollController@store`.  In my web routes, it is within a resource e.g. `Route::resource('polls', 'PollController');`

Comment: @Graeme ... updated my answer. Let's see if that works for you!

Comment: @Graeme : Switching from 127.0.0.1 -> localhost did the trick. Curious if it works for you also! (see my new answer above). (Additionally, drop the dd() and use print_r() instead due to the Laravel lifecycle)

Comment: Thanks again however that still didn't work. I may try just create a new laravel project and pull over the work i've done so far and see if the issue persists. Really strange one.